# Adding custom field to Basic Client Integration option

Tags: mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

I have setup Express Checkout using the Basic Client Integration, but I would like to know how I could use the example given in the API and add IPN custom field to let my mysql server which service ID update when the payment is completed. I have never messed with Paypal API before.

Comment: Can you add some code or some site reference? So we know exactly of what you talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an ajax call to your server in the `onAuthorize` callback from the paypal button. Then you can update your database and show a confirmation page once that's done.